# How are these codes different? The second one somehow works but why doesn't the first one work?

Tags: python, if-statement

I made this calculator code and for reasons I want to know, only the first if statement runs even if it's false. The second one works after I copied an answer I found here but I still don't understand, how are they different?

First code:

```
 while True:
    print("Welcome to my calculator")
    print("Type end")
    print("Pick one of the options: ")
    print("Add, Sub, Div, Mul")
    user_input1 = input()
    if user_input1 == "end":
        break
    user_input2 = int(input("Select the first number. \n"))
    user_input3 = int(input("Select the second number. \n"))
    if user_input1 == ("Add") or ("add"):
        answer = user_input2 + user_input3
        print(answer)
    elif user_input1 == ("Sub") or ("sub"):
        answer = user_input2 - user_input3
        print(answer)
    elif user_input1 == ("Div") or ("div"):
        answer3 = user_input2 / user_input3
        print(answer3)
    elif user_input1 == ("Mul") or ("mul"):
        answer4 = user_input2 * user_input3
        print(answer4)
    else:
        print("rip")
```

Second code:

```
while True:
    print("Welcome to my calculator")
    print("Type end")
    print("Pick one of the options: ")
    print("Add, Sub, Div, Mul")
    user_input1 = input()
    if user_input1 == "end":
        break
    user_input2 = int(input("Select the first number. \n"))
    user_input3 = int(input("Select the second number. \n"))
    if user_input1 == ("Add") or user_input1 == ("add"):
        answer = user_input2 + user_input3
        print(answer)
    elif user_input1 == ("Sub") or user_input1 == ("sub"):
        answer = user_input2 - user_input3
        print(answer)
    elif user_input1 == ("Div") or user_input1 == ("div"):
        answer3 = user_input2 / user_input3
        print(answer3)
    elif user_input1 == ("Mul") or user_input1 == ("mul"):
        answer4 = user_input2 * user_input3
        print(answer4)
    else:
        print("rip")
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This does not do what you seem to think it does:

```
if user_input1 == ("Add") or ("add"):
```

It is always going to be false because the `or` is making ("Add") and ("add") to be cast as booleans so the logical expression like BOOL or BOOL can be evaluated. So unless "user_input1" is equal to the boolean True it will be false (as opposed to being equal to one of the strings).

Maybe if you want it shorter you can do this:

```
if user_input1 in ("Add", "add"):
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is your use of the `or` statement. In Python 3, all non-zero numbers and strings have `True` truth values, so saying `user_input1 == ("Add") or ("add")` is the same thing as saying `user_input1 == ("Add") or True`, which is always `True`.

Also your `while` statement has the wrong indenting so appears to be doing nothing. Is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

when you do `user_input1 == ("Add") or ("add")` it evaluates separately both sides of the `==`, so it will do ("Add") or ("add") which will only retain the first non empty value in this case "Add".
this is why you have to do the evaluations separately:
`user_input1 == ("Add") or user_input1 == ("add")`

One way for avoiding this is to put all in caps like this:
`user_input1.upper() == ('ADD')`

Answer (score 0):

actually, the second answer is

```
while True:
print("Welcome to my calculator")
print("Type end")
print("Pick one of the options: ")
print("Add, Sub, Div, Mul")
user_input1 = input()
if user_input1 == "end":
    break
user_input2 = int(input("Select the first number. \n"))
user_input3 = int(input("Select the second number. \n"))
if user_input1 == ("Add") or user_input1 == ("add"):
    answer = user_input2 + user_input3
    print(answer)
elif user_input1 == ("Sub") or user_input1 == ("sub"):
    answer = user_input2 - user_input3
    print(answer)
elif user_input1 == ("Div") or user_input1 == ("div"):
    answer3 = user_input2 / user_input3
    print(answer3)
elif user_input1 == ("Mul") or user_input1 == ("mul"):
    answer4 = user_input2 * user_input3
    print(answer4)
else:
    print("rip")
```

and you have to indent everything to be level with

`while True`

in the first example..Also, if you did that, then you also need to unindent any useless indents.